# htaccess RewriteCond not always working

Tags: linux, .htaccess

I am having a problem on a Linux web server.

Basically I have the following htaccess code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

which works fine, so that if I go to www.mydomain.com/blablablajrehkhsg it shows me the www.mydomain.com/index.php page.

But it doesn't always work. for example on a specific URI like www.mydomain.com/specific-uri I get a 404 page not found error.

I even tried to add the following line in my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/specific-uri
```

so htaccess becomes:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/specific-uri
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

but it still won't show mt the index.php page.

Please help, I have no idea what it could be.

thanks

Comment: RewriteCond works fine. Do you have any other rules?

Comment: I do have other Rules, but they are unrelated. Even if I delete the other rules and just leave this code, I still get the problem.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I solved the problem.

basically there was a page on the root called specific-uri.php which was in conflict. Normally the:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

condition will take care of this, but I think apache was converting /specific-uri to specific-uri.php before the htaccess condition.

So I added this:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

before the condition in the htaccess which I believe it tells apache to stop looking for similar content from the uri.

Now I can see the /specific-uri and the specific-uri.php separetly.